Problem reading saved model in Tensorflow 2.16 and Python 3.11
I am having problems to save/load files in tensorflow.
Here a sample of the code.
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=(3,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
    ],
)
model.save(r"d:\model.keras")
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"d:\model.keras")

I am using Anaconda/Python 3.11, Tensorflow 2.16.1, Keras 3.3.3
